# how to convert string to date or datetime in php

Tags: php, json, date, datetime

my PHP script is receving "/Date(1403071826510)/" as a JSON date. How can I convert this to PHP Date or DateTime?

this is what I am doing:

```
$milliseconds = (int) preg_replace("/[^0-9 ]/", '', $strDate);
return json_encode(Date('d/m/Y h:m',$milliseconds/1000));
```

but my casting is returning 2147483647 instead of 1403071826510 because my OS is 32 bits.

Any idea how to get the Date or DateTime from the string received?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for a regex here. You can simply extract the seconds from the middle of the string and work with that:

```
$sec =substr("/Date(1403071826510)/", 6, 10);
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$sec);                // 2014-06-18 06:10:26
```

Mindful of @zamnuts comment here's a regex version that handles early dates:

```
preg_match('#Date\(([0-9]{0,10}?)([0-9]{1,3}\))#',"/Date(1403071826510)/",$matches);
$dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $matches[1]);
```

Comment: What if the date is Jan 1, 1970 1 8:20am? In this case the timestamp is simply 500s (500000ms) and the use of `substr` is insufficient.

Comment: @zamnuts True enough, but we don't know what range of dates is involved here. On a practical basis I haven't had to deal with a date that would be affected by that in more years than I can remember.

Answer (score 3):

Strip off the milliseconds BEFORE you convert. Since it's a string, you just lop off the last 3 digits using `substr()`, and then cast to `int`

```
$js_timeval = '1403071826510';
$php_timeval = (int)substr($js_timeval, 0, -3); // 1403071826
echo date('r', $php_timeval);

Wed, 18 Jun 2014 00:10:26 -0600
```

Answer (score 1):

Marc B's answer works just fine (+1), but for completeness (and since I already did the work), I was thinking to use the [BC Math extension for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), which must be installed and is not included by default. BC Math allows PHP to work with arbitrarily large numbers.

Consider the following:

```
$input = '/Date(1403071826510)/';

$ms = preg_replace('/[^0-9 ]/','',$input);
var_dump($ms); // string '1403071826510' (length=13)

$sec = bcdiv($ms,'1000');
var_dump($sec); // string '1403071826' (length=10)

$date = Date('d/m/Y h:m',$sec);
var_dump($date); // string '17/06/2014 11:06' (length=16)
```

All conversions use `String`. [Divide the parsed milliseconds using bcdiv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php) by `'1000'` and pass that into `Date` for the seconds timestamp.